# How to parse a json array with an array inside to a java object with a Set

Tags: java, json, set

I'm trying to parse an array json to an objects array.
This is my class:

```
public class EntityDTO {

    private String entityId;

    private String name name;

    private Set<String> tags;

    private Boolean value;
}
```

This is the json string:

```
"[{"entityId":"xxx","name":"xxx","tags":"[TAG_1, TAG_2]","defaultValue":false}]"
```

But when I'm trying to do this:

```
Gson json = new gson;
gson.fromJson(defaultResponse.getBody(), EntityDTO[].class);
```

It cannot cast the array of tags inside the string to the tags sets of the object.

How can I do this?
note: I cannot change my EntityDTO class.

Comment: is that the _actual_ json? (if so, this will get closed as typo, as you just forgot the " around the tag names)

Comment: @njzk2 what do you mean? This is a valid json.

Comment: I see. `"[TAG_1, TAG_2]"` is a string. In no way is it a collection of strings. It's not even a json representation of a string collection inserted as string. You have to start by figuring out what is the form of representation used for this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was no choice but to add another class, and use it to represent the JSON